# Generating periodic packets in Ns2

Tags: tcl, ns2, packets

I have to generate a periodic stream of packets with period Ta, burst rate Rb with burst duration of Tb. For example every 50ms I want to generate packets of size 5Mb for a duration of 10ms. What are the parameters I should manipulate to achieve this. I'm new to ns2 so, so far I know of:
`set packet_size_` and `set rate_`
But how do I include the burst duration? Are there any configurable parameters I'm missing?

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Answer (score 2):

By default, I don't think you can do such thing in ns2. You have to change application file such as CBR.cc manually to support it.